# When abutting Ipe decking inline is it best to meet it at 90 deg or perform a 45 deg scarf cut?

Tags: cutting, decking, joints

I'm using Ipe with mounting clips.  When abutting two pieces is it best to scarf 45° or just abut it at 90°?

Comment: Welcome to DIY! Can you maybe a diagram of what you're trying to do? It would help you in getting an answer.

Comment: Do not think one is better than the other.  It probably comes down to which one you think looks better, and which you can make look good, if you need to cut a perfect 45 or adjust the cut so it makes a perfect corner.

Comment: I'm realizing now from the reference to scarf/scarph cuts that we're talking about straight butts (inline end joints), not corners. It's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Ipe is extremely dense and thus hard to cut.  Your tools will last longer if you make shorter cuts.

Comment: Don’t forget to seal the cut ends of the ipe right after you cut them. (It’s not that seconds matter, it’s that you’ll get distracted and forget if you don’t do it right away.)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to always (just about) use 90's. You want and need any and all joints to only happen on top of a joist or other structural member and be fully supporting both boards' ends...of course NEVER "float" a joint, not even in plywood or drywall (horrendously wrong practice).

There are however 2 cases that 45's can work fine. Typically for a decorative pattern. One is, when the joint runs inline or parallel with a structural member. Or Two, when the joint occurs on a beam or additional blocking can be installed. Otherwise, the boards can be very twisty if not at least mostly supported and doubled nailed or screwed.